# Is it possible to insert HTML into a Wix template?

Tags: html, velo

I'm trying to insert this snippet from Psychology Today

```
<!-- Professional verification provided by Psychology Today --> 
<a href="https://www.psychologytoday.com/profile/[snip]" class="sx-verified-seal"></a> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://member.psychologytoday.com/verified-seal.js" data-badge="13" data-id="[snip]" data-code="[snip]"></script> 
<!-- End Verification -->
```

However, it seems there isn't a normal way to insert some HTML into Wix.

Comment: I don't know about wix, but in WordPress, you can use javascript. With javascript, you can append an HTML content to the body. Maybe you can do something like that?

Answer (score 1):

1) Click Add ﻿﻿on the left side of the Editor.

2) Click More.

3) Click HTML iframe, or drag it the relevant location on your page.

4) Enter the code (must use HTTPS only).

5) Click Apply.

Taken from https://support.wix.com/en/article/adding-html-code

Good luck!

Comment: Step 4 you say enter "code" but if it's an iFrame, I believe you mean enter a "URL", is that right? HTML and a URL are not quite the same.

Comment: You will be adding your HTML in there. In the live site, this code will be put within an iFrame.

Comment: How to make that code adapt to the overall style, i.e. infer and inherit the proper CSS classes?